# How to find out which page is in use

Tags: wordpress

iThemes exchange has this function that I can call from anywhere in my theme which tells me if one of the iThemes pages is active. So for example if I wanna find out if the current page is an iThemes exchange page I do:

```
    if (it_exchange_is_page()) {
```

or if I wanna find out if its the login page I do:

```
    if (it_exchange_is_page('login')) {
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make a function like this for my own membership plugin. So I tried adding this function to the bottom of my membership plugin file:

```
function check_members_page() {

if ( has_action('custom_members_page') ) { return TRUE; } 
else { return FALSE; }
```

}

then in the function which renders the login page, I add:

```
add_action('custom_members_page','fake_function');
```

the problem is that the render login page function gets called after I run has_action so fake_function hasn't been hooked to the custom_members_page hook yet. What do you do in situations like this where you need to make a function that will be available everywhere (i.e. in your theme, in other plugins etc.), but that function needs some information from somewhere further down?

Comment: get_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_page_template', true ); will get you the current template file being used if that is any good to you - where $post_ID is the ID of the post/page - it returns the .php file name - my_template.php etc

Comment: I need to be able to get the page slug from the themes functions.php file. I don't even know how to get the post ID in there, $post isn't available in functions.php.

Comment: Try "global $post;" - to get the post object and then $post->post_name will get you the current post/page slug https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to call these wordpress functions directly from the functions.php file, before many of these functions (like get_post_meta or the $post object) are even defined. I'm still getting my head around the whole action hooks thing.